# How Linux kernel is synchronized with Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel, repository, git, github

As Ubuntu uses Linux kernel. Since Ubuntu has his own git repository while Linux kernel has its own repository. So can these two different GitHub repo is in sync. Can someone explain? These questions can be further apply on mint which Ubuntu derivative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu kernel team maintain their own flavors of the Linux kernel for Ubuntu, because of the feature set Ubuntu depends on.

The Ubuntu kernel FAQ states:

> #### What differentiates the Ubuntu Kernel from the upstream Linux Kernel?
>
> Ubuntu kernels are rebased against stable releases only through the
> development cycle, with many patches on top of the stable tag. Once
> the final release is made the master branch is never rebased again.
> While stable updates (post release) are usually applied, we sometimes
> make patch decisions that are counter to the stable releases.
>
> So, the best one could say is that Ubuntu kernels are only loosely
> based on upstream stable. You'd have to examine the changelog to know
> exactly what goes into a particular kernel.
>
> With every Ubuntu kernel release, we attempt to remain as true to the
> upstream Linux kernel as possible. However, there are inevitable
> patches which we carry on top of the upstream Linux kernel which
> differentiates the Ubuntu kernel from the upstream Linux kernel. This
> document attempts to describe the general set of patches which are
> carried and why: [Kernel/FAQ/UbuntuDelta](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/FAQ/UbuntuDelta)

> #### Given an Ubuntu kernel package version how do we find the exact mainline release it is based on?
>
> The exact upstream mainline tag from which the Ubuntu kernels were
> forked can be found in the [mainline kernel mapping](https://people.canonical.com/%7Ekernel/info/kernel-version-map.html) table.

So the repository trees are not "synchronized". Rather, the Ubuntu team maintains the Ubuntu kernels with upstream Linux kernel patches, as well as other patches as needed.

*Sidenote: Distributions that are derivatives of Ubuntu (which are actually off-topic here) usually use the Ubuntu kernels instead of maintaining their own kernel flavors.*

Comment: Than is Linux mints also maintains their own version of Ubuntu, and is it true for all distros that are derived from Debian, arch and Ubuntu?

Comment: No. Most derivatives of Debian and/or Ubuntu use Debian or Ubuntu's kernel. Some derivatives may build their own kernel, but the majority don't. It's a lot of effort to maintain, for little benefit.